# Find and replace using sed with special characters $'{[}]

Tags: linux, shell

```
TempVar=$(cat <<\!eof!
${parameters['env']}
!eof!
)
echo $TempVar
```

OutPut:

```
${parameters['env']}
```

But same doesnt work when i use in sed

```
sed -i "s/${TempVar}/dev/g" file.txt
```

Comment: If you escape any part of the here-document delimiter, the contents are treated the same as a single-quoted string.

Comment: Side note: I'd drop `!` in the marker, it might trip history expansion.

Comment: Agreed; I suspect that's why it's being escaped in the first place.